# Virtualmin DNS problems

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, virtualmin

i'm pretty new to Ubuntu and Virtualmin and I got a problem.

I'm creating a webserver with virtualmin local use only (it's running on virtualbox) so the ip is 10.0.2.15 and I'm trying to make the DNS work.

According to virtualmin it should add everything to the DNS records on his own, but I can access my website from the IP but not from the domain name.

Any help ? Please be detailled I'm pretty new at this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: have you registered the domain name? Everything I can find about auto DNS in virtualmin  refers to having a registered domain. these are available through several registrars. godaddy.com comes to mind. However you say that this is for local use only. Can you better define exactly what you are trying to accomplish in this fashion? Perhaps there are some workable alternatives.

Comment: It's basically more for a school assignment kind of thing. I don't want to register it online, because it shouldn't be needed for a local environment.

Comment: This appears to have an answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/281495/how-should-i-set-up-a-fqdn-and-intranet-sandbox-12-10-server-that-wont-be-public. You can help us help you by trying that and commenting on it's efficacy and/or upvoting the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Support for virtualmin is available [here](https://www.virtualmin.com/support)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I set up a FQDN and Intranet Sandbox 12.10 Server that won't be public](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281495/how-should-i-set-up-a-fqdn-and-intranet-sandbox-12-10-server-that-wont-be-publi)

Answer (score 1):

Configure virtualmin with a local domain like `virtualmin.local` or something like `virtualminlvm.com`, the important part is add the domain-ip relation somewhere, you either can install a dns server like [dnsmasq](https://www.linux.com/learn/dnsmasq-easy-lan-name-services) or simply add them to `/etc/hosts` file like

```
10.0.2.15    virtualmin.local
10.0.2.15    virtualminvm.com
```

Note that using .com (or other real tld) will hide the route to real site (if exists) from you.